# Laravel update currently logged in user's model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have:

```
    $lang = Session::get('applocale');
    if ($lang) {
        User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['language' => $lang]);
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this through Auth? Perhaps something like Auth::user()->language = $lang or something?

---

```
public function switchLang($lang)
{
    if (array_key_exists($lang, Config::get('languages'))) {
        Session::set('applocale', $lang);
        if(Auth::check()) {
            auth()->user()->update(['language' => $lang]);
        }
    }
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

---

languages.php (config)

```
return [
    'en' => 'English',
    'cn' => '中文',
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['language' => $lang]);
```

you can use:

```
auth()->user()->update(['language' => $lang]);
```

However in both cases (your code and mine) you should be sure that user is logged otherwise you might get exception here

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work :( Please see my edit.

Comment: And when using your code does it work? How your `languages` config file looks like?

Comment: + the question is, do you have set `language` in `$fillable` property for your `User` model ?